# How to force TypeScript to ensure that all const, let & var variables must be declared with their types

Tags: typescript, variable-types

I have just installed TypeScript, having come from a Pascal / Java background and expected the following snippet to fail to be compiled for two reasons (line 2 - message used before it is defined, line 4 - Type boolean is not assignable to type string)

I was expecting TypeScript to raise an exception at line 1 - 'Variable defined without specifying Type'.

```
let message;
console.log(message);
message = "Hello this other world";
message = false;
console.log(message);
```

In order that TypeScript should do its job I have to amend the first line to

```
let message: string;
```

The two exceptions (line 2, line 4) now both get highlighted as expected.

My tsconfig.json is defined as

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2020",
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "outDir": "javaScript",
    "sourceMap": true
  }
}
```

Am I missing an attribute within the tsconfig.json file that would enable this feature or do I have to just accept that I have to remember to provide TypeScript with the data type each time I use `const`, `let` or `var`

Interestingly, the functionality appears to be as expected when declaring functions. For example

```
const addOne = (i: number): number => i + 1;
const addOneEquals = (addOne(4) === false);
```

If you remove the `:number` function return type, the  comparison still flags up as an exception *types *number* and *boolean* have no overlap*. This is due to TypeScript being able to deduce the type from the function body and so is still safe even if I forget to define the return type, although I would prefer TypeScript to force this for me.

If you remove the `: number` from the parameter, TypeScript flags up the exception at `(i)` of *Parameter 'i' implicitly has an 'any' type.*

Therefore, in conclusion, why doesn't `let message;` flag the same exception - i.e. *Variable 'i' implicitly has an 'any' type.* Unlike functions, TypeScript can't defer the type from the simple `let` statement and so I would expect an exception as it is unsafe to continue without knowing.

Comment: Normally this should be under [`noImplicitAny`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noImplicitAny) which is implied with `"strict": true`. However, it seems like `let message;` will implicitly set `message` to `any` but it will not cause an error. However `(message) => console.log(message)` will have an error because `message` is implicitly `any`. Seems like a weird way the rule is enforced. I don't know if there is a good explanation for it.

Comment: @VLAZ >  I don't know if there is a good explanation for it. That is the conclusion I had come to but being so new to TypeScript, I couldn't see why the basic 'Hello World' type example wasn't detected as TypeScrips main aim is to ensure consistency of types. Having said that, when I came to use TypeScript on an existing  JavaScript source, of course, global variables are actually very rare and then they are normally objects derived from classes. TypeScript immediately illustrated how many possible issues there were that would only be picked up at Runtime if using JavaScript